# How to initialize a RemoteMessage object with a Json file?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am dealing with FCM messages and I have the following function:

```
  public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
  {
   final Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
   //...
  }
```

For testing purposes, I have a Json file containing data- and I want to send that Json file from my test method to `onMessagereceived()` . Hence I need to initialize a `RemoteMessage` object with the Json file and pass this RemoteMessage object to the function. How do I initialize this?

My JSON file:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id" : "4422",
        "type" : "1",
        "imageUrl" : "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/android-boot-logo_634639.jpg",
        "smallTitle" : "DoJMA v2",
        "smallSubTitle" : "Update now from Google Play Store",
        "ticker" : "New update for DoJMA",
        "contentInfo" : "",
    "link" : "https://photo2.tinhte.vn/data/avatars/l/1885/1885712.jpg?1402763583",
        "className" : "HomeActivity",
        "page" : "2",
        "bigTitle" : "DoJMA Android app version 2 released!",
        "bigSubTitle" : "Hi folks! New DoJMA update is here! Major redesigning and improvements! This app was made by the Mobile App Club.They work really hard man...and get good products",
        "bigSummaryText" : "Update now"
     },
    "registration_ids": ["dQYmpLUACXQ:APA91bGl-NoIMJ2_DcctF5-OA8ghyWuyrMfsz3uhlj1BySl6axkAsmv5y_7YGfpQQJ2E0lP_fTcxpHpZdkJzY1tbcWA36e78ooxC_b0a1PAank9gFIAUHVZkHKmZT70MPZosCgvRlVfq","dfLXnRI36qY:APA91bFyjLblijVIjGLCGWVeB1B0z5j_3TYqRytJ-8hvuUESpDlX59gWF3hU-I-kA4VrRCPpEVFWl18ZarnPjqxxtZgFkVxoLr77HRex27VN7Mh3xupWykmKq_nnVIlVzrODKwKI7ktM"]
}
```

Comment: Pass your data in JSONObject json = new JSONObject("Your json String"); inside of onMessageReceived method.

Comment: @Janak but how do I convert that to a remoteMessage object?

Comment: You want this Json in your response?

Comment: @Janak I want to pass this Json to `onMessageReceived()` , so I have to convert it to a `RemoteMessage` object. My question is how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can test using Postman For Single User.

**Send a notification with a JSON payload**

URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Headers:

```
Authorization: key=<your-api-key>
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body (click on the 'raw' tab):

```
{
  "to": "dQYmpLUACXQ:APA91bGl-NoIMJ2_DcctF5-OA8ghyWuyrMfsz3uhlj1BySl6axkAsmv5y_7YGfpQQJ2E0lP_fTcxpHpZdkJzY1tbcWA36e78ooxC_b0a1PAank9gFIAUHVZkHKmZT70MPZosCgvRlVfq",
  "data": {
    "id": "4422",
    "type": "1",
    "imageUrl": "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/android-boot-logo_634639.jpg",
    "smallTitle": "DoJMA v2",
    "smallSubTitle": "Update now from Google Play Store",
    "ticker": "New update for DoJMA",
    "contentInfo": "",
    "link": "https://photo2.tinhte.vn/data/avatars/l/1885/1885712.jpg?1402763583",
    "className": "HomeActivity",
    "page": "2",
    "bigTitle": "DoJMA Android app version 2 released!",
    "bigSubTitle": "Hi folks! New DoJMA update is here! Major redesigning and improvements! This app was made by the Mobile App Club.They work really hard man...and get good products",
    "bigSummaryText": "Update now"
  }
}
```

Source : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Initializing a [`RemoteMessage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage) object is **not** possible.

---

Attempting to access initialize a RemoteMessage from your own class would return an error:

> 'RemoteMessage(android.os.Bundle)' is not public in 'com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage'. Cannot be accessed from outside package.

I presume you're attempting to do this for testing purposes (*stubbing*?). In general (not gonna say *best practice*, since I'm not that entirely sure that it is best practice), it is advisable to have a *separate method* that accepts a specific value that you need. Referring to the [official example (`onMessageReceived`)](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/c3376b13cadf15b0cdf9dcc9075e4bad2973bbe4/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java) (removed some stuff):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
            scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

}

/**
 * Schedule a job using FirebaseJobDispatcher.
 */
private void scheduleJob() {
    // [START dispatch_job]
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            .setTag("my-job-tag")
            .build();
    dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
    // [END dispatch_job]
}

/**
 * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
 */
private void handleNow() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
}

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Focusing on the comment that mentions:

> Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

This points out the `sendNotification()` method that accepts a String parameter. Depending on your case, instead of attempting to pass an initialized `RemoteMessage` (which sadly isn't possible, or at the very least is **not** advisable), you could simply pass an object that your method needs.

With that, you pretty much tested the method that handles the message without depending on an object that isn't a class you made in the first place.

<sub>PS: Some of my explanations can be confusing, but I hope this made sense.</sub>